# Implement dynamic 2 player splitscreen based on player positions

Tags: unity, camera

Having a local 2 player game, when the distance between the player is big enough, we have a splitscreen whose shape is defined by the angle between the two players. When they get close enough to each other it should fall back to single screen and when they get farther, the screen zooms out before becoming a splitscreen again.

Pretty much the way it's demonstrated in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XzIzHKwVDH4

How would that be implemented? What would be a decent GameObject-Hierarchy for this?

Answer (score 1):

In the description for that video (click "show more") you'll find he also posted a tutorial on how he did it.

The tutorial starts [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iTNnWVolRLk).

He also has it posted on the asset store [here](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14553).